# Minimal and maximal elements of a partially ordered set

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I've been trying to comprehend the concept of minimal and maximal elements of a partially ordered set, but the explanations I find often involve the use of Hasse diagrams. Can someone please explain the concept of minimal and maximal elements of a partially ordered set with an example using the definitions below?

**Definition 1.1.1.** Let $(S, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $S$. $a \preceq b$ means "$a$ precedes $b$" or "$b$ dominates $a$". If $a \preceq b$ and $a \neq b$, we say "$a$ properly precedes $b$" or "$b$ properly dominates $a$" and write $a \prec b$.

**Definition 1.1.2.** An element $p \in S$ is called a **minimal element** of $S$ if there is no element in $S$ which properly precedes $p$, i.e. $x \preceq p \Rightarrow x = p$. Similarly, an element $q \in S$ is called a **maximal element** if there is no element in $S$ which properly dominates $q$, i.e. $q \preceq y \Rightarrow q = y$.

Thanks.

Comment: Just look at examples: In $\{a,b,c,d, e\}$ with $a\succ b$ and $c\succ d$, the elements $a$ and $c$ are maximal, the elements $b$ and $d$ are minimal, and $e$ is both maximal and minimal. In $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual order, $0$ is minimal and there is no maximal. In $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual order there are no maximal nor minimal elements.

Comment: I understand that for $a \succ b$ and $c \succ d$ implies that $a$ and $c$ are maximal, and, $b$ and $d$ are minimal, and the other examples you provided. But I want to ask why $e$ is both maximal and minimal?

Comment: Check the definition. There is no other element comparable to $e$ besides $e$ itself. So, if some $x\in\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ satisfies $x\succeq e$, then $x=e$, or of $e\succeq x$ also $x=e$.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and let $S = \mathscr P(X) \setminus \{ \varnothing, X \}$ be the set of all non-empty proper subsets of $X$, partially ordered by set inclusion.  Then the minimal elements of $S$ are exactly the singletons because no element of $S$ is contained in any singleton.  Conversely, the maximal elements of $S$ are the complements of singletons because the complement of a singleton is not contained in any element of $S$.

Notice that the definition is very dependent on exactly which elements you do and don't allow into $S$.  If you consider $S'= \mathscr P(X)$, then $S'$ has exactly one minimal element ($\varnothing$) and exactly one maximal element ($X$).

Comment: @Abdulrahman I suggest you use infinite examples.  Finite posets will always have at least one minimal element and at least one maximal element.  Infinite posets may have both a minimal and maximal element, only one, or neither a minimal nor a maximal element.

Comment: @Abdulrahman  Let me give you an exercise to test your ability to work with these concepts.  Let $$S = \{ A \subseteq \Bbb N \mid A \text{ is infinite and } \Bbb N \setminus A \text{ is infinite} \}.$$Use set containment to make it a poset.  $S$ is the collection of subsets of $\Bbb N$ that are infinite and also have infinite complements.  The set of even positive integers is an example of an element of $S$ because there are infinitely many even positive integers and infinitely many positive integers that aren't even.  Prove that $S$ has no minimal elements and no maximal elements.

Comment: Let $X, X' \in (S, \subseteq)$ where $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is infinite and $X'$ is its complement. Since $(X, X') \not\in (S, \subseteq)$ and $(X', X) \not\in (S, \subseteq)$, then there exists no minimal or maximal elements.

Comment: @Abdulrahman I'm afraid that's not correct.  Let me suggest you work on it some more.  Assume toward a contradiction that $X \in S$ is maximal, and then find some element of $S$ that strictly contains $X$.  This argument directly uses the definition of "maximal."  If you still can't get it after some more work, I suggest posting my exercise as a new question, **being sure to include in your question the relevant definitions and all work that you have done**.

Comment: I've sent this question to one of my seniors for more elaboration. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Abdulrahman To see for yourself why your proposed proof is wrong, examine how it plays out if we change the definition of $S$ to include *all* non-empty proper subsets of $\Bbb N$ (not just infinite subsets with infinite complements), which is a poset that *does* have both maximal and minimal elements, as demonstrated in the answer above.  You'll see that your proposed proof would carry through without change to yield the false conclusion that this revised poset has neither minimal nor maximal elements.  Since that conclusion is wrong, there must be a problem with the proof.